# Component is briefly rendering without styles on first render

Tags: css, reactjs

When I open my react app, the component below flashes with `width:100%`, probably because it inherits it from the material-ui card.

In my react app there are a lot of these components being rendered, each with their own width which are based on the parent component's data. I set the width with an inline style based on the props.

As I understand, the component has the inline style as it is created and there should be no delay to apply it. However I see all the `SceneThumb` components with 100% width for a a fraction of a second, before they apply the given inline style.

If I change the css of `scene-thumb-parent` to include some width, say 10% for example, then I'll see them all with 10% for a fraction of a second, before the inline style is applied. That makes me think there is a delay in applying inline css, but it really puzzles me..

Is this to be expected of react? Or of html in general? Is there any way to reduce this inline style application delay? Maybe it's something to do with the dev hot reloading setup I get from `create-react-app`?

**SceneThumb.js** *(code that is irrelevant to the question has been omitted):*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './scene-thumb.css';
import Card from 'material-ui/Card';

class SceneThumb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='scene-thumb-parent'
        style={{width:this.props.width, left:this.props.left}}
      >
        <Card
          className={this.props.selected?'scene-thumb-selected':'scene-thumb'}
        >
          <span>
              Hello world!
          </span>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SceneThumb;
```

**scene-thumb.css:**

```
.scene-thumb-parent {
  position:relative;
  text-overflow:clip;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  min-width: 12px;
}

.scene-thumb-selected {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.scene-thumb,.scene-thumb-selected {
  padding: 2px;
  margin:2px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing here that the width prop is initially `null` or some other value. Please add a `console.log(this.props.width)` at the top of your `render()` and post the output.

Comment: Please show your parent componet, propable probably @Chris has right

Comment: @Chris you got it. It was a problem with calculating the width based on a video's duration. if the video wasn't loaded, I was using zero as duration and that lead to division by zero in calculating the width. Could you write as an answer so I can accept it? Or maybe this is not general enough and I should just delete the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` prop is initially null or some other value. A moment later, the prop is updated which triggers another render. This is why you're seeing the flash you're talking about.

You can test this by adding the following to your `render()` function:

```
console.log(this.props.width)
```

You'll probably see it logging at least twice with different values.

There are many ways you can fix this. What makes most sense would depend on the rest of the application, and your personal preference. Regardless, here's *one* way:

```
render() {
  if(!this.props.width) return null; //if it's null, render nothing.
  return (
    <div className='scene-thumb-parent' style={{width:this.props.width, left:this.props.left}}>
      <Card className={this.props.selected?'scene-thumb-selected':'scene-thumb'}>
        <span>Hello world!</span>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```